# Данные сами добавляются в базу при обновлении страницы

Tags: php, база-данных

Почему при обновлении страницы `reg.php`, не вводя при этом ничего в форму,  данные в базу добавляются сами, то есть добавляется последние введенные данные, удалял базу, и при обновлении страницы тоже самое. Код: http://ideone.com/UFzy0B

```
<?php header('content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');?>
<form action="reg.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" required> <br/>
<input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин" required> <br/>
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Пароль (мин. 6 знаков)" min="6" required> <br/>
<input type="password" name="confirm_pass" placeholder="Подтверждение пароля" min="6" required> <br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Регистрация">
</form><br/>


<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//creating a db
if(!file_exists("db.db")){
    $db = sqlite_open("db.db");
    if(!$db) echo '<p style="color:red;">Таблица не создана</p>';
    //creating a table
    sqlite_query($db, "CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, login TEXT, pass INTEGER); ");
    exit;
}

//открытие БД
$db = sqlite_open("db.db");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $confirm_pass = $_POST['confirm_pass'];
    if($pass == $confirm_pass){
        $pass = md5($pass);
        sqlite_query($db, "INSERT INTO users(id, name, login, pass) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$login', '$pass')");
    }else
        die("Пароли не совпадают!");
}
//количество пользователей
$users = sqlite_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users");
echo "Всего пользователей: " .sqlite_num_rows($users). "<br/>";

//вывод записей
while ($res = sqlite_fetch_array($users)){
    echo "Имя: " .$res['name']."<br/>";
    echo "Логин: " .$res['login']."<br/>";
    echo "Пароль: " .$res['pass']."<br/>";
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

Comment: Хороший вопрос, почему никто не отвечает? Данные сами ж добавляются, мистика, да и только!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Почитайте про [повторную отправку формы](https://www.google.by/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B), и данные сразу перестанут добавляться сами собой.